# AWS DataSync some errors in your task execution. No affected files in CloudWatch logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-datasync

I'm getting this error when I run a DataSync task:

> Transfer and verification completed. There were some errors in your task execution. See a list of affected files in CloudWatch logs. If no files are listed in CloudWatch logs, contact AWS Support.

The error code is:

> CompleteWithErrorLogsWithNoVerificationErrorTaskReports

The error happens during the prepare phase.

I have no idea how to further debug this or what could cause this to happen. The task stopped working randomly; it might be a temporary bug.

Comment: For more information, I'm moving files from an S3 bucket to an EFS volume. The task worked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting AWS Support, they got back to us with an answer.

In the S3 bucket we had a path as such:

```
s3://<BUCKET_NAME>//test/path/file.txt
```

DataSync didn't like the double slash since it's not valid in most file systems. So, after renaming the bad path, everything worked.